# fancybox show pdf

Tags: jquery, fancybox

hi i am trying to display a PDF with fancybox but I can not.

I have this code:

```
 $(".fancybox").fancybox({
      'frameWidth': 100,
       'frameHeight':495,
       'overlayShow':true,
       'hideOnContentClick':false,
      'type':'iframe'
})
```

and

```
<a class="fancybox" href="/symfony2/web/app.php/pdf/2"> show pdf</a>
```

but shows me that way generated pdf:

http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-pantallazo-8110661.html

Does anyone know how to solve the problem to display the facybox correctly? a greeting.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Could you explain what exatly does not work for you? It should work - http://jsfiddle.net/zqJFp/

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf">Open pdf</a>

​$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width  : 600,
    height : 300,
    type   :'iframe'
});​
```

Answer (score 7):

this work for me i hope work for you!

```
<a class="btn btn-info btn-sm btn-hover gallerypdf" data-fancybox-type="iframe" href="../../assets/img/exp_2493_parte-3.pdf"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></span></a>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".gallerypdf").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        autoSize: true,
        type: 'iframe',
        iframe: {
            preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `iframe: {
preload: false // fixes issue with iframe and IE
}` this fixed the issue for IE 9

Answer (score 3):

Fancybox attempts to automatically detect the type of content based on the given url by looking at the file extension - gif, jpg, pdf and so on. In your case it cannot be detected, since your url is not ending with a ".pdf", therefore you have to set the type manually.

The accepted solution is fine because this can be done using the `type` option when you initialize the fancybox, however it won't work if you have mixed contents (images AND pdf together). In those scenarios, you can use the `data-type` inline attribute and tag each individual entry.

For example, you can do this:

```
<a href="getimages.php?id=123" data-type="image">
    Show image
</a>
<a href="getpdf.php?id=123" data-type="iframe">
    Show pdf
</a>
<a href="getajax.php?id=123" data-type="ajax" data-src="my/path/to/ajax/">
    Show ajax content
</a>
```

... and so on.