# How to show PDF inside FancyBox 1.3.4?

Tags: c#, jquery, pdf, fancybox

I have a grid with multiple records.  When the user clicks on a row, the form submits to the server where I would generate the PDF and stream it back.  Then FancyBox is to take this PDF data and display it.  Here is how I generate the PDF data:

```
var id = grid.SelectedItems[0].GetDataKeyValue("RECORD_ID");
var byteArrayPDF = GeneratePDF(id);
Response.Clear();
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline;filename=recorddetail.pdf");
Response.BufferOutput = true;
Response.BinaryWrite(byteArrayPDF);
Response.End();
```

The browser recognizes the data stream and display the PDF correctly.  Now I need to display this PDF inside FancyBox.  Please help.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution

```
<a class="fancybox" href="http://samplepdf.com/sample.pdf">Open pdf</a>

​$(".fancybox").fancybox({
    width  : 600,
    height : 300,
    type   :'iframe'
});​
```

[fancybox show pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293980/fancybox-show-pdf)

Comment: Thank you for your response, Coelho! I don't have the PDF file on the server. I need to trigger grid's item click to submit to the server where the PDF file is generated based on the record ID submitted and sent back.

Comment: Yes, the code example in my question is my server code that generates the PDF. As long as the client has a PDF plug-in/reader, the PDF is rendered correctly.